# final table and add elements in android

Tags: android

I have a final table:

```
    final Item itemsList[] = new Item[]{
            new Item(R.drawable.per1,contacts.get(0).getName(),contacts.get(0).getTitle(), contacts.get(0).getPhone(),contacts.get(0).getTitle(),contacts.get(0).getEmail())

    };
```

And this is my problem. I want to add to this table more than one element. Elements I get from list "contacts". And If I have 10 elements in list "contacts" I want to add to "itemList" 10 elements but I can't do this because my itemList is final and it must be final, because I need this way. How I can add number of elements to itemList dynamically?

Comment: What is the reason of making it final ? If want to update it later then there is no sense of make it final.

Comment: I add this data in intent: intent.putExtra("my.header.id", itemsList[arg2].name); where arg2 is number of choosen element from list. when I delete final I get error

Comment: Why declare it final if it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `itemList[]` final means that you cannot change reference once it's initialized, not its content. So, if you know number of elements when you initialize your `itemList` you can do it like

```
int itemsCount = ...;
final Item itemList[] = new Item[itemsCount];
```

and then set it's content like

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
     itemsList[i] = new Item(...);
}
```

Also, as Jave suggested using `List<>` might be more suitable in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best of just using a `List` if you need to add unknown amounts of Items:

```
final List<Item> myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
myList.add(new Item(...));
//add more Items
```